# «Журавль» — все ли согласные звонкие?

Tags: фонетика

Правда ли, что в слове "журавль" все согласные звонкие?

Comment: Если вам дан ответ, который помог, отметьте его галочкой.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы имеете в виду фонемы — единицы нематериальные — то да, в слове *журавль* они все звонкие.

Что касается звуков, то они должны отражать ваше произношение. Если вы произносите всё звонко ([жура́вл̥']), ответ на ваш вопрос положительный. Уверен, что большинство носителей русского литературного языка произносят всё звонко.

Заметьте, что в конце слова плавный [л'] образует вершину слога, то есть является слоговым. Таким образом, слово трехсложно: жу=ра=вль.